# How to define the last request of chain of ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a chain of ajax requests. 
They are used for copying category tree from one parent to another. 
In case if any of copied categories has subcategories, the ajax request is run once again. This loop ends only after there are no any subcategories left.

Proccessing all subcategories in ohe request causes server timeout error when there are too many subcategories, that is why separate ajax requests are used for subcategories.

Here is the basic scheme of the code:

```
function ajaxProcessCategories(arguments){
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(jsonData)
    { 
      ...
      if(jsonData.hasOwnProperty('children'))
        for (var i in jsonData.children)
          ajaxProcessCategories(arguments);
    },
    ...
  });
}
```

it works just fine. The categories are copied properly.

But I can't find a way to display a message, when copying process is over. The problem is that on ajax success it is unknown wheter any other request will be sent.

So is there any possible way to define the last ajax request within a function? Something like .ajaxStop(). But ajaxStop() works for all ajax requests within $(document). I need to find the last ajax request within my function.

Comment: Use [.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to group all your ajax requests into a single deferred that you can attach a handler to when the are *all* done.

Comment: If you just need to *know* this information as opposed to having it available in your script, try watching the network activity with a debugger console for whatever browser you're using.

Comment: Wouldn't you know this on the serverside, so you could just send an additional parameter that says if it's the last one or not ?

Comment: @MattBurland - could you show an example of how that would work with recursive ajax calls ?

Comment: Agree with Matt. As alternative - simple json object can be used with two props: requestSent:0 and requestComplete:0. When you enter your function - increase requestSent. When request is completed - increase it. When numbers are equal - you're done.

Comment: @MattBurland, thanks for valuable comment. It looks like an elegant solution, but I can't get it working. As adeneo mentioned, could you please show an example of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a counter to determine when the last request has completed. Increment the counter at the beginning of `ajaxProcessCategories()` and decrement it at the end of the success callback. When the counter reaches zero, you are done.

However, making recursive AJAX calls like this is a bad idea in general. If the calls are timing out, it points to a performance problem with your server-side implementation.

Comment: See @Matt Burland's comment in your question. It's a better solution than my counter.

Comment: Thanks, this kind of counter does the job.
@Matt Burland's comment might be better, but I couldn't get it working, so at the moment I am using the counter model.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a progress variable to track when you're done:

```
var progress = 0;

$(function() {
    $(document)
        .ajaxStart(function() {
            progress++;
        })
        .ajaxComplete(function() {
            progress--;

            if (progress == 0) {
                //do finished actions
            }
        });
});
```

The [ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxComplete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) attach to the document to track all jquery ajax calls.